# MySQL SELECT NOT IN

Tags: mysql

I have table:

```
+----+--------------+--------------------------+
| id | user         | mac                      |
+----+--------------+--------------------------+
|  3 | user003      | 148fc78371212b           |
|  4 | user004      |                          |                          
|  5 | user005      | 171248fc78312d           |                                
|  6 | user006      | 212e148fc78371           |
+----+--------------+--------------------------+
```

I need to select only ID if mac encrypted value NOT EXISTS duplicate in row mac.

If for example:

- user003 is having edit on form gui and leave old encrypted mac address 148fc78371212b it needs to get count from result in mysql 1
- user003 is having edit on form gui and enter new encrypted mac address 212e148fc78371 it needs to get count from result in mysql 0 (so that i can then alert message Duplicate MAC address)
- i need query that checks if user does not change its own mac address to allow editing (return 1) and if user change mac address and that address exists in mac address for another user (return 0) MAC address exists.

I try using this:

```
SELECT mac FROM users
WHERE user='user003' AND mac='148fc78371212b' OR mac NOT IN (SELECT mac FROM users);
```

But i always get count result 1...i could not figure out how to archive above result?

So my query needs to look like this in theory:

```
SELECT mac FROM users WHERE user=? AND mac=? AND MAC DOES NOT EXISTS IN MAC 
FIELD EXCEPT WHERE user=? AND mac=? (so to exclude searching duplicate mac 
on defined user)
```

Comment: can't you group by user and mac with predicate having count(*)=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is just one record per `user` and if `mac` is also unique, then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT mac,
       CASE 
          WHEN user_with_newmac IS NULL THEN 2
          WHEN user_with_newmac = user THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END AS flag
FROM (
   SELECT mac,
          user,
          (SELECT user FROM users WHERE mac = ? ) AS user_with_newmac       
   FROM users
   WHERE user = ?) AS t
```

The subquery `(SELECT user FROM users WHERE mac = ? )` returns the user (if any) having the *new* value of the mac address. The outer query uses this value to calculate the flag:

- If `user_with_mac` is `NULL`, then the new mac address does not exist at all yet. So, `2` is returned.
- If `user_with_mac = user`, then the mac address has not changed and `1` is returned.
- Otherwise, if `user_with_mac <> user`, then some other user has the mac address, so `0` is returned.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/MDLKP21249)

Comment: SELECT mac,
       CASE 
          WHEN user_with_mac IS NULL THEN 2
          WHEN user_with_mac = user THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END AS flag
FROM (
   SELECT mac,
          user,
          (SELECT user FROM users WHERE mac = '148fc78371212b' ) AS user_with_mac,                

   FROM users
   WHERE user = 'user003') AS t;  and i im getting this error in mysql: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM users
   WHERE user = 'user003') AS t' at line 12

Comment: I get above error..could you please check your sql query?

Comment: @John You are using the initial version of my query that contained a redundant comma. I have made an edit correcting this error. Please check the Demo I've also included in my answer. It works ok with the sample data provided.

Comment: YOu are right i im working in node js using mysql wrapper so i need to add \ when going sql query to next row..now it works perfect thanks.

Comment: @John I am glad I was able to help you.

Comment: This is far from efficient and vulnerable to race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your description, the attribute mac can be null, if it is not null, then it must unique.

If that is the case, then your approach is wrong. You should not be allowing users to insert data into the table which makes the table inconsistent. Consistency should be described in the database, therefore you should not be checking from your application that the operation will create an inconsistency.

However achieving this is a bit tricky. You can't use a unique index because you allow multiple NULL values; you need to use a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_transaction BEFORE INSERT ON yourtable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (0<(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM yourtable 
    WHERE mac=NEW.mac 
    AND user<>NEW.user
   )) THEN
   SIGNAL 'Sorry - no dups'
  END IF
END
```

Comment: Thanks .... i use above solution...works great...multiple users edit is not worry because performance is great...i will have around 5-6edits in every 10minute so above code is very good. Thanks for pointing me out for performance issue.